# Firefox is dropping XUL what does this mean for Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Will NoScript continue to offer the advanced functions we are used to. Will HTTPS Everywhere still offer the Observatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions are important and relevant to Tor and privacy, but only the plugin's maintainers are able to answer you - they do control the functionalities of the add-ons: what will be, what won't be and how it will be. Ask them - on the Mozilla Firefox add-on description pages there're are contacts.